# Pythonic way to add each previous element in list

Tags: python, python-2.x

It's a very simple question, but I wonder if there is a more pythonic way to add each previous elements in a list like this (for example with a list comprehension maybe) :

```
input : L = [4, 2, 1, 3]
output : new_L = [4, 6, 7, 10]
```

Which I've done this way :

```
def add_one_by_one(L):
    new_L = []
    for elt in L:
        if len(new_L)>0:
            new_L.append(new_L[-1]+elt)
        else:
            new_L.append(elt)
    return new_L

new_L = add_one_by_one(L)
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2, Python 3 or both?

Comment: I'm using mostly Python 2

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Note that Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), recommends using `lower_case` names for variables, so I changed all your `L`s to `l` and all your `new_L` to `new_l`.

```
l = [4, 2, 1, 3]
```

You should keep track of the cumulative sum in a variable. This way you avoid having to test whether the `new_l` already has an element in it:

```
def add_one_by_one(l):
    new_l = []
    cumsum = 0
    for elt in l:
        cumsum += elt
        new_l.append(cumsum)
    return new_l
```

As an alternative, you could use a generator to avoid having to build the list inside the function (if you are just going to iterate over it later, this is the most *memory-efficient* way):

```
def add_one_by_one_gen(l):
    cumsum = 0
    for elt in l:
        cumsum += elt
        yield cumsum

new_l = list(add_one_by_one_gen(l))

# This takes basically no additional memory (only one float/int):
for x in add_one_by_one_gen(l):
    print x
```

(Replace `print x` with `print(x)` in Python 3.x.)

Probably the *fastest* way to do it would be using the `numpy` function [`cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html):

```
import numpy as np

new_l = np.cumsum(l)
```

Comment: Not everyone has, needs or wants to use NumPy. Let's not make it the JQuery to JavaScript questions of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I agree. This is why I proposed two non-numpy alternatives (where the generator is probably even better if the OP does not actually need the cumulative sums all at once).

Comment: BTW, `list(itertools.accumulate(l))` is faster than `numpy.cumsum(l)`. I only tried when `l` was a Python list, as that's the use-case.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Good to know. Makes sense that it only starts to be faster when used on bumpy arrays

Comment: *numpy* arrays, of course.

Comment: @Graipher No, arrays are *always* bumpy in Python.

Answer (score 25):

In Python 3 `itertools` gained a new function [`accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) that does what you want.
I'd recommend that you instead used this function. Or if you can't if you're in Python 2 to upgrade.
This would single handedly change your code to:

```
from itertools import accumulate

new_l = accumulate(l)
```

---

If you however done this as a learning exercise, then I'd instead use iterators.
I'd first change `l` to an iterator, via `iter`.
Which would allow you to use `next` to remove the default value.
After this I would then loop through the iterator and `yield` rather than `new_list.append` the new values.
This can allow you to get something like:

```
def accumulate_sum(l):
    l = iter(l)
    try:
        total = next(l)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    yield total
    for item in l:
        total += item
        yield total
```

Which funnily enough is almost exactly the same to how it's done in [`itertools.accumulate`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L3465-L3490).
If you wanted to at a later date use a different function rather than addition, then you could pass that as a function, to call on each iteration.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the `iter` function, very useful.

Answer (score 8):

### 1 Using Python 2

#### 1.1 Ninja way

Is fun and good for learning python, but don't go for it in production code

```
from operator import iadd

l = [4,2,1,3] 
reduce(lambda result, x: iadd(result, [result[-1] + x]), l, [0])[1:]
```

#### 1.2 Explicit way

I will just copy @Grapier solution for this because I would do the same:

```
def add_one_by_one_gen(l):
    cumsum = 0
    for elt in l:
        cumsum += elt
        yield cumsum
```

### 2 Using Python 3

```
from itertools import accumulate

accumulate(l)
```

Comment: For the first solution, why would you want to use `iadd` instead of just `result+[result[-1]+x]`?

Comment: @kalj there is no particular reason for that, you can use result + result[...] if you want to, which is a more obvious way to do that.

Comment: @Alex is the `reduce` really *that* hard to read? You could always define an 'ungolfed' named function to pass to reduce if it required annotations. I don't write python daily, but summing a list says `reduce` to me in any HOF language...or is there some other reason you wouldn't use it in prod?

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm pretty upset by current python community, you would be surprised to see how many of python devs don't even know about the existence of reduce or any high-order functions in python. And a reason for that, in my opinion, is that most of the companies don't have any kind of coding culture so basically, people don't really care about things they write until they are working.

Comment: @JaredSmith This kind of abuse had led to `reduce` being moved to `functools`. Note that he isn't exactly *summing* a list - he traverses the list with an array, adding new elements to that array. Things like this are better done with iteration, or comprehension (well, not in this case, but in general), leaving `reduce` for tasks where set of homogenous elements is combined into one element of similar "type" (like summing a list, if we didn't have a `sum` for that).

Comment: @Daerdemandt I just ported a nodejs program that deals with a heavily-nested data structure to python, I can state with certainty that nested comprehensions with conditional clauses are *much* harder to read than the equivalent JavaScript reduces (and resulted in me pulling out a number of named functions, basically turning the comprehension into a `map` call), even though python is IMHO a far more readable language. And I have a strong preference for HOF over iteration for any number of reasons. Your point about what he's really doing with that list is well-taken though.

Comment: @JaredSmith > *heavily-nested data structure* `yield from` is great, instead of nested comprehensions you can have composition of *named* generators which explicitly say what they do and what parts of outer scope they use. As for HOFs, they are incredibly fun, but when I don't want to be asked how exactly my code works I try to keep shenanigans toned down.

Comment: @Daerdemandt I likely missed the composed generator solution due to python noobishness. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Only vaguely related (high-orderism and the like), but this problem is begging for Haskell. `accumList ell = (head ell) : zipWith (+) (tail ell) (accumList ell)` I tried to port this to python, but it just gets stuck in the recursion.

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked for a Pythonic solution and I see none so far, I propose:

```
new_L = [sum(L[:i+1]) for i in range(len(L))]
```

It's certainly less efficient than an accumulator -- it's \$O(\frac{n^2}{2})\$ vs \$O(n)\$ -- but it uses a list comprehension as you suggested.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Indeed this oneliner (or, more precisely, lack of more efficient oneliners) demonstrates that sometimes syntax gets in your way - unless you resort to `[element + this_list()[-1] for element in L]`, lending some magic from [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/204297/).

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through the array, adding the previous value to the next. The same way you would do it in C. Simple, short, reasonably efficient, and no fancy tricks.

```
def add_one_by_one(L):
    new_L = list(L)
    for i in range(1, len(new_L)):
        new_L[i] += new_L[i-1]
    return new_L

print(add_one_by_one([4, 2, 1, 3]))
```

Of course, in Python 3 using accumulate is clearly superior.

Answer (score 2):

As Matthew Cotton posted, using a list comprehension is a very clean one-liner.

You can also do it recursively. Here is what I came up with.

```
def accum(L):
    if len(L)<2: return L
    return accum(L[:-1]) + [sum(L)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Hereby another 'Pythonic' variant of Matthew's answer which does not require the use of both `range()` and `len()`:

```
[sum(L[:i[0]+1]) for i in enumerate(L)]
```

`enumerate` is handy to use since it creates tuples containing the index and value at that index.