# Project Euler Problem #12 - Highly divisible triangular number

Tags: python, programming-challenge, factors

[Project Euler Problem #12](https://projecteuler.net/problem=12)

> The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural numbers. So the 7th triangle number would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28. The first ten terms would be:
>
> ```
> 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...
> ```
>
> Let us list the factors of the first seven triangle numbers:
>
> ```
> 1: 1
> 3: 1,3
> 6: 1,2,3,6
> 10: 1,2,5,10
> 15: 1,3,5,15
> 21: 1,3,7,21
> 28: 1,2,4,7,14,28
> ```
>
> We can see that 28 is the first triangle number to have over five divisors.
>
> What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five hundred divisors?

I know this question has been asked here many times regarding long run times (my problem) but I don't understand the explanations so here is my take;

```
def euler_12(num):
    i = 0
    for n in range(1,num):
        list= []
        for j in range(1, n**2):
            if (n+i) % j == 0:
                list.append(j)
                if len(list) == 500:
                    print(n+i)
                    break
        i = i + n
```

```
euler_12(num)
```

I understand this is probably a very poor way to do it, and it also takes forever to run, so any comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: The code as posted fails to run due to `NameError: name 'num' is not defined` on the last line.

Comment: @PeterTaylor That's clearly an example of how to use the code. Just change `num` to the num you want.

Comment: @Peilonrayz, which is what? The problem which this is attempting to solve is quite small and specific, so the code which solves it should run standalone without requiring the user to guess a value for an undocumented parameter.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I won't pick a number for you. I have previously solved Project Euler questions this way, does that mean I didn't really solve them? And does the above code work? From the looks of it it does. We also get tons of questions without example input and output, why should this question be off-topic when others arn't?

Comment: -1 from me because the Code does not solve the problem. I was not able to find the result. for small values of `num` the program finishes without printing a result and  for larger `num`the program hangs up without printing a result.

Comment: besides that: `list`is not a good variable Name because my programming Environment says : redefining built-in list

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8829/31562)

Answer (score 5):

Split up your code. You're:

1. Generating all triangle numbers.
2. Factorizing all triangle numbers.
3. Displaying when you get the first triangle number with 500 or more factors. And ending the program.

These sound like some good functions to me.

And so you could use:

```
def triangle_numbers():
    return ...

def factors(number):
    return ...

def euler_12():
    for number in triangle_numbers():
        if len(factors(number)) >= 500:
            return number

print(euler_12())
```

---

To generate all triangle numbers you can use [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) and [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate). If you're not running Python 3 you can [implement `accumulate`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/149381), or manually perform the calculations yourself.

```
import itertools

# Python 3
def triangle_numbers():
    return itertools.accumulate(itertools.count())

# Python 2
def triangle_numbers():
    sum = 0
    for i in itertools.count():
        sum += i
        yield sum
```

---

Currently your `factors` code would be:

```
def factors(num):
    list= []
    for j in range(1, num**2):
        if (num) % j == 0:
            list.append(j)
```

This has a couple of problems.

1. You don't need to use `num ** 2`. The largest maximum you need is `num + 1`.
2. You can use `int(num ** 0.5) + 1`.

   This is as \$\sqrt{n}^2 = n\$. With the equation \$n = a * b\$, allowing you to find \$a\$ when you've found \$b\$.

And so you can use:

```
def factors(num):
    for div in range(1, int(num**0.5) + 1):
        if num % div == 0:
            yield div
            other = num // div
            if other != div:
                yield other
```

This has change this piece of code from \$O(n^2)\$ to \$O(\sqrt{n})\$. So if \$n = 10000\$, you'd only need to check \$100\$ numbers, rather than \$100000000\$.

You will also have to change the return value of `factors` to a list to use `len`.